# How to find solutions in set of intgers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is there a simple way to find set of solutions in integers.  For example, find integer solution of

(1) $x^2 + y = y^5 + x$

(2) what is **Extend Ellenberg’s approach**? For what type of equations can be solvable by this approach/method?

Thanks!

Comment: Observation: $$x(x-1)=y(y^2+1)(y^2-1)$$ and $(x,x-1)=(y,y^4-1)=1$ and $(y^2-1,y^2+1)|2$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee! can we get solutions from your observation???

Comment: Formula for solving the equation no.  Because the number of solutions of course.

Comment: @individ! I am not asking you particular method or formula. I am asking you that, how to find integer solutions by any observations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question (0), in general the answer is no, there is no simple way.  There is no general algorithm for Diophantine systems ([Hilbert's 10th problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem)).

For (2), what is Ellenberg's approach?

EDIT:

(1) Since the equation is quadratic in $x$, it is reasonable to solve for $x$:
$$ x= \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{4 y^5 - 4 y + 1}}{2}$$

So we need $y$ to be an integer such that $4 y^5 - 4 y + 1$ is a square. 
(Note that if it is a square, its square root is odd, so the division by $2$ won't be a problem).
A search for such $y$ in the integers $0$ to $10^6$ finds only $1,2,3, 30$.
These correspond to $x =  1$ or $0$, $6$ or $-5$, $16$ or  $-15$, $4930$ or $-4929$ respectively.  I wouldn't be surprised if these were all the solutions.

Comment: You want to say that you cannot decide to write a formula solution.      Such equations : $aX^2+bXY+cY^2=jZ^2$ ? Many equations to solve.  You just need to understand what can be solved and which are not.

Comment: @individ! how to solve my first (1)?

Comment: There exist solutions: $x=5,y=2$;$x=15,y=3$;$x=4929,y=30$

Comment: @Robert Iserel! I have few questions on your post.

Comment: @Robert Israel! (1) How you checked values up to 10^6? do you use any software. if yes, please let me know. (2) can you find such y's as well as x's for beyond 10^6? (3) The problem looks that, it has infinitely many solutions. can you generalize?

Comment: Robert, I took the liberty of correcting a math typo in your quadratic formula (it's $+1$ inside the square root, not $-1$).

Comment: Note: The OP has posted a follow-up at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955891/perfect-square-then-it-is-odd/955953

Comment: @numbertheory : I used Maple.
Since (also according to Maple) the curve $x^2 - x + y - y^5$ is irreducible and has genus $2$, Faltings's theorem says it has only finitely many rational points, and therefore only finitely many integer solutions.

Comment: @BarryCipra: thanks for catching and fixing this.

Comment: @RobertIsrael! could you please discuss what is Falting'f theorem and how my question is related to this theorem?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faltings%27_theorem