# Perfect square then it is odd

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have tried several values by trail and error and I concluded the following fact.

'if the $S = 4x^5-4x+1$ is perfect square for some integer $x$, then square root of $s$ is always an odd integer'

**could you find values of integer x, in order to make S is perfect square???**

Thanks!

Comment: $S$ is odd, so you are correct.

Comment: As @TobiasKildetoft suggests, you are really observing "if $n^2$ is odd, then $n$ is odd". This is another way of saying "if $n$ is even, then $n^2$ is even". The particular polynomial form of $S$ doesn't really have much to do with it.

Comment: This question appears to be motivated by an answer given by Robert Israel to the OP's earlier posting at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955057/how-to-find-solutions-in-set-of-intgers -- so it looks like what the OP really wants to know is what (odd) values of $x$ make $4x^5-4x+1$ a perfect square (which is more or less what the boldface part of the posting here seems to ask). Robert found the values $x=1$, $2$, $3$, and $30$, and speculates there are no others.

Comment: Oops, I put the "(odd)" in the wrong place.  I should have said "what values of $x$ make $4x^5-4x+1$ an (odd) perfect square." I probably shouldn't have inserted it at all.

Comment: @Barry Cipra! you are correct. I am looking for all such x values corresponding to values of y. Both in intgers.

Comment: a quick run with sage also finds only those numbers, now to prove it...

Answer (score 2):

For the added question of finding such $x$, I find $1,2,3,30$ Excel then reports $36$, but [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%284%2836%5E5-36%29%2B1%29) shows it is only close.

Comment: Ross, you may not have noticed my comment below the OP.  Your findings agree with Robert Israel's.

Comment: @BarryCipra:  Python runs out of precision and reports 9409, but Alpha disagrees.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the terms this way:

$$S = 4(x^5 - x) + 1$$

The first term is even by inspection, because it's four times an integer.  Adding $1$ makes it odd.  The square root of an odd perfect square is odd, because it's the product of two odd numbers.

Comment: !could you find values of inetger x, in order to make S is perfect square.

Comment: That wasn't part of your problem statement.  The statement assumed that odd perfect square $S$ existed already.